# Add day slider to jQuery UI datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

Referring to the standard examples for the jQuery ui datetimepicker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#slider_examples

I am  looking for a way to add a **day** slider in addition to the sliders for hours, minutes,seconds etc.

HTML:

```
<div id="datetimepicker1"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss'
});
```

I prepared a basic jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anet04mv/3/

Any hint to proceed is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want the user to use a Slider instead of picking a day from the list of days? If the Month changes, do you want the number of days to adjust along with it? It's not clear the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure oif this will help you. What I suggest is to collect the days from the calendar and then make the slider.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/anet04mv/6/

Here are the highlights:

```
  function harvestDays(target) {
    var dayElems = target.find("[data-handler='selectDay']");
    var days = [];
    dayElems.each(function(ind, el) {
      days.push({
        day: parseInt($(el).text()),
        selected: $(el).hasClass("ui-datepicker-current-day")
      });
    });
    console.log("Found " + days.length + " Days. ", days);
    return days;
  }

  function makeDaySlider(target, ds) {
    var current = 0;
    $.each(ds, function(k, v) {
      if (v.selected) {
        current = k;
      }
    });
    var $cont = $("<div>", {
      class: "ui-daypicker-div"
    });
    $cont.append("<dl></dl>");
    $cont.find("dl").append("<dt class='ui-daypicker-label'>Day</dt>");
    $cont.find("dt").append("<dd class='ui-daypicker-day'></dd>");
    $slide = $("<div>", {
      class: "ui-tpicker-day-slider"
    });
    $cont.find("dd").append($slide);
    $cont.insertAfter(target.find(".ui-datepicker-calendar"));
    $slide.slider({
      max: ds.length,
      value: current
    });
    console.log("Created Day Slider for " + ds.length + " Days, current day selected: " + (current + 1), $slide);
  }
```

Currently, this will work until the month is changed. Just feed the new calendar back through and replace the slider to get the new number of days.

Since I do not know what you're trying to accomplish exactly, I am not sure if this is what you're looking for. I considered that you might want the slider to change the selected day... which would require a callback for `slide`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. What should I change to make it work with `<input id="datetimepicker1">` instead of `<div id="datetimepicker1"></div>` in the HTML?  Updated JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/PhazzAgtig/k7ura2L0/